# Loading an access form into memory

Tags: ms-access

I am currently encountering a problem while running a query which is calling a form. My problem is similar to the one described in this link ( http://www.techonthenet.com/access/queries/filter1.php ). I need a solution to this problem. Thanks!

EDIT: My problem is that I cannot get the form to open while querying once I type [Forms]![FormName]![ControlName]. All I get is an input dialog as in the mentioned article.

Comment: Please describe your problem here.

Comment: 1) You could run a function first to see if the form is open or not before you run the query. 2) I know this doesn't answer your question but I don't recommend referencing a form control from within your query. Is this a saved query? Where is being used or where are you running it from? Isn't there any way you could use a function or sub instead and pass in a variable?

Comment: thanks for the reply. Actually my requirement is that I have to take user input using a combo box rather then a normal input box that gets displayed during normal user input. Is there any other way to have a user input combobox/dropdown ?

Comment: In what context are you using the query? In a form or report? If so, then use the WHERE argument of DoCmd.OpenForm/DoCmd.OpenReport and pass the value from your control. You don't want to muck about with the query, which is more versatile if you haven't saved a WHERE clause in it (particularly one that is hardwired to require that a form be open).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to open the form first before executing the query.

Comment: Question: How? can you point me to a resource/ article for this. It only works if I first explicitly click on the form and select an option and then press ok. Now when I run the query, it returns only those values associated with my selection. My scenario is that I want to run the query and when I do that I should see my form as a dialog displaying a combobox as user input. Once the user selects something, that should go to the query and it should return the relevant rows. Is that possible? Thanks for your help!

Comment: You can try to open the query as soon as you open the form.  Add a Form Open event with this code: `DoCmd.OpenQuery "QueryName"`.